# Moving view of ViewController after modalViewController dismissed

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have two ViewControllers: A and B. A is a delegate of B. I am presenting B from A and when I dismiss it, I am trying to move the views of A. I have methods set up in the delegate to listen to when B is dismissed to try to move the views. This is what I am using now when B is dismissed, but it doesn't work. How can I get this to work?

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    NSLog(@"view dismissed");
    [self moveViews:self];
}];

- (IBAction)moveViews:(id)sender
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                     animations:^{
                         self.view.center = CGPointMake(160, 250);
                         //self.tableView.center = CGPointMake(160, -100);
                         self.addView.center = CGPointMake(160, 240);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
}
```

Comment: what does moveViews do? you are passing the current view controller to the other view controller, but what are you doing with the actual view properties of the view controller?

Comment: sorry I should have posted this too, added to main question

Answer (score 0):

looking at your moveViews method, you aren't moving the views from one view controller to the other. You are moving the position of the view. The problem is that the view controller being dismissed will no longer be a part of the screen, so it wont be visible. My recommendation would be to implement iOS 5 UIViewController containment and add the dismissed view controller as a child view controller of the other view controller. The reason for this is because the information contained on the modal view controller (the controls, target for actions and the model) is a part of the modally presented view controller. Check the documentation for the UIViewController class and the containment mentioned here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: But I want to call this method when the previous ViewController is loaded again, not while the new controller is present.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is, that you call here `[self moveViews:self];` the method on the view B.

Have a id (for example named sender ) property in B.

When you make the transition set the sender property in B to A.

Call

```
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    NSLog(@"view dismissed");
    [self.sender performSelector:@selector(moveViews)];
}];
```

then B will be dismissed and calls method moveViews on A.

In A you have a method

```
    - (void)moveViews
{[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                     animations:^{
                         self.view.center = CGPointMake(160, 250);                        
      }
                     ];
}
```

should work, have fun

Comment: Tried it, just crashes after it is called. Any idea why?

Comment: Oh, forgot to remove the id parameter in the moveViews method. Now moveViews is called, but it doesn't do anything to the views for some reason.

Comment: Let me guess, the view you want to move is a fullsize view ?!?! change the centerpoint to something like (100, 200) and it will move. You say at the moment with (160,250) that the new centerpoint is on the same position as the old one. So thus the view does not move at all.

Comment: Yes, but when it is called the view is at (160, 720), so shouldn't it move then? There is another view at (160, 250) but I want to move this view on top of it.